# Does the operation of addition on the subspaces of V have an additive identity? Which subspaces have additive inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was reading Linear Algebra Done Right. I came across the following question (Ch-1, Q12), for which I have solution , but I am having little confusion regarding it:

Q12. (a) Does the operation of addition on the subspaces of V have an additive
identity?

Sol. The subspace {${0}$} is an additive identity for the operation of addition on the subspaces of V. More precisely, if U is a subspace of V, then U + {${0}$} = {${0}$} + U = U.

This is quite obvious as subspaces are itself vector spaces and so must have {${0}$}, or even their addition, whether uniquely expressed or not. If not expressed uniquely then it won't be a direct product but will still be a subspace (Am I right here about subspace?)

Q12. (b) Which subspaces have additive inverses?

Sol. For a subspace U of V to have an additive inverse, there would have to be another subspace W of V such that U + W = {${0}$}. Because both U and W are contained in U + W, this is possible only if U = W = {${0}$}. Thus {${0}$} is the only subspace of V that has an additive inverse.

What I don't get here is that since a subspace is a vector space itself, why do  we need to consider another subspace W for U to have additive inverse? Can't U contain its own element's additive inverse?

Comment: The set on which this addition is defined is the *set of subspaces of $V$*. Therefore, if an element of this set ($U$) is to have an additive inverse, that additive inverse must also lie in the set of subspaces of $V$. This is a different notion than the addition defined on the set of *elements of the vector space $V$*: for this addition, definitely every subspace of $V$ contains the additive inverse of each one of its elements. But that's a different operation and question altogether.

Comment: I think I got your point... Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the operation of addition on subspaces of V have an additive identity? Which subspace have additive inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265927/does-the-operation-of-addition-on-subspaces-of-v-have-an-additive-identity-whic)