# Does the operation of addition on subspaces of V have an additive identity? Which subspace have additive inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not clear about the sum(and direct sum) operator on subspaces, how to use them? please offer me some applications about this operation, really really appreciate it.

Comment: For $\;U,W\le V\;,\;\;U+W:=\{u+w\;:\;\;u\in U\,,\,\,w\in W\}\;$ . It's easy to check this is a subspace of $\;V\;$ . Whta's the problem with this and why do you think this addition on the subspaces of $\;V\;$  has to have an identity, inverse and etc.?

Comment: And also about the associativity and commutativity.

Comment: Suppose O is the additive identity of U, then U+O=U

Comment: So then you have an identity: the zero or trivial vector subspace....but you clearly cannot have inverses, as $\;U\subset U+W\;$ , for any two subspaces $\;U,W\;$ .

Comment: Speaking of identity, how about U itself? U+U=U?

Comment: An identity element in some set under some operation must be the identity for **all** the set's elements. In the case you produce, we'd rather say $\;U\;$ is idempotent, not even call it "an identity for itself".

Comment: If I want know all of the terminologies and methods you mentioned above, which book , in addition to Linear Algebra Done Right which I'm now going through, I need to read? I'm self-studying LADR book, and I really need some suggestions, thanks a lot!

Comment: Google the terms you want. In the different sites appearing there you'll be able to find some references to bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commutativity and associativity for supspace addition follow from its elementwise definiton, i.e., because they hold for vector addition.
The $0$ space is an identity for subspace addition.
However, there is no inverse for any subspace $0\subsetneq W\subseteq V$ because adding another subspace cannot make it smaller - you always have $W\subseteq U+W$. Hence the subspaces of $V$ form an abelian group under subspace addition only if $V=0$.

Comment: If U is a subspace of V, what is U+U?